# php APC uptime problem

Tags: php, uptime

I am on LAMP with Alternative PHP Cache. It worked fine until yesterday when I updated the website and changed a few mySQL queries (I don't see the how it would affect APC opcode cache)

Today I see that the load has increased on the server and I see in Alternative PHP Cache, that the uptime of APC is somewhere around 15 minutes then it gets restarted.

At this point the APC cache is only about 20% full of the available 30Mb. Using for opcode cache only. During this 15 minutes the cache works fine (99,8% cache hits). After this unwanted restart the APC cache is empty. Why is it restarting? Where can I find the logs for it?

Thanks, Hamlet

Comment: It always restarts after 16 minutes

Comment: I see this in the apache logs 
[Thu Jan 14 13:41:14 2010] [notice] Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Thu Jan 14 13:41:15 2010] [notice] Apache/2.2.11 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.11 OpenSSL/0.9.7a mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 PHP/5.2.8 configured -- resuming normal operations

Comment: fixed it, it was a cpanel update that caused apache to restart gracefully every 15 minutes because of logrotation...

Comment: Heh, 15 minute log rotation. Updates can be annoying. Had APC knocked out altogether last month due to one.

Answer (score 1):

Check cpanel and see if that is causing apache to restart.